# Dynamic Dashboards are under limit but still getting error of limit?

Tags: dashboard

Running Enterprise Edition of Salesforce which currently hace limit of 5 dynamic dasboards. I created the following report to know the total number of dynamic dashboards which is 4 at the moment.

[image]

And when I tried to create a new dashboard I received this error.

> Error: You reached the limit for dashboards run as the logged-in user

Why?

Comment: Register your upvote - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IRSu

Alternative solutions to fix, refer the salesforce article - 
Find the dynamic dashboards in my organization - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326117&type=1&mode=1 (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326117&type=1&mode=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your report is looking nice but it is not giving you complete picture that you require. Instead hop on to the developer console and run this soql.

```
SELECT DeveloperName, Type, Id FROM Dashboard 
WHERE Type IN ('LoggedInUser', 'MyTeamUser')
ORDER BY DeveloperName Asc
```